# Adding page numbers to PDF with Lucee cfpdf

Tags: coldfusion, railo, lucee, cfpdf

Everything I have found about CFPDF says that the way to add page numbers to a PDF is like this

```
<cfpdf action="addFooter" source="#finalFile#" name="mypdf" 
       text="Page _PAGENUMBER of _LASTPAGENUMBER" />
```

The problem is every reference I have found is for coldFusion 9 and before and I am wondering if maybe the Lucee guys didn't include this functionality because I get an error that says

```
Attribute text is not allowed for tag cfpdf
```

Is this a syntax issue or an oversight by Lucee/Railo not to put this in.

I am merging a group of PDFs using CFPDFs merge feature that this is working correctly but I now need to put page numbers on the PDF and that is were I am hitting a wall.

Here is the a more complete picture of what I am trying to do. The only part that isn't working is the `addFooter` line

```
    <cfpdf action = "merge" destination="#finalFile#" overwrite="yes"> 
        <cfloop array="#arrayOfPdfs#" index="k">
            <cfpdfparam source="#k#">
        </cfloop>
    </cfpdf>

    <cfpdf action="addFooter" source="#finalFile#" name="mypdf" 
           text="Page _PAGENUMBER of _LASTPAGENUMBER" />

    <cfloop array="#arrayOfPdfs#" index="k">
        <cffile action="delete" file="#k#">
    </cfloop>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did a little searching and here is what I found. Remember that Lucee was previously Railo. I found your exact issue reported as a bug in Railo back in August 2011 - [cfpdf addfooter not supported](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RAILO-1463) It looks like that bug was never addressed.

The Lucee docs mention the ability to add a header/footer using `cfpdf` in the lead-in paragraph but not in the tags attributes - [Lucee documentation for cfpdf](http://docs.lucee.org/reference/tags/pdf.html)

> Create PDF portfolios - **Add and remove header/footer from PDF documents** - Optimize PDF documents

(my emphasis) But there is no mention of `addheader` or `addfooter` beyond that.

This just mirrors the original Railo documentation - [Railo documentation for cfpdf](http://railo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tags/cfpdf/)

I am guessing that this bug was never resolved and now exists (still exists) in Lucee. I would create a new issue for the Lucee group to revisit this - https://luceeserver.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa

It is interesting that it seems to accept the `addfooter` action just not the `text` attribute. That makes it seem like a bug.

**UPDATE 11/18/2021**

From Andy's comment below "*It looks like a fix is coming from the PULL requests at github.com/lucee/extension-pdf/pulls specifically [github.com/lucee/extension-pdf/pull/31](https://github.com/lucee/extension-pdf/pull/31)*" it appears that a fix may finally be coming for this issue. Thanks for the update Andy!

Comment: I have registered this as a bug but given that it is as old as it is I may have to come up with an alternate solution :(

Comment: It looks like a fix is coming from the PULL requests at https://github.com/lucee/extension-pdf/pulls specifically https://github.com/lucee/extension-pdf/pull/31

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will add that to the answer in the form of an update so it is more visible for others reaching this page.

Comment: You can (like I have today) pull the pull request in to a new local branch, and using ANT compile the extension and deploy it if you want it sooner.

e.g. 
git fetch origin pull/<pull-request-id>/head:<local-branch-name>
git checkout <local-branch-name>